# How to use cloud firestore to get data in an ionic 4 app

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I was following a tutorial where a guy showed how to build a news app with ionic 4 using the news API. I also want to create a news app that shows summarized news from different sources on a particular topic but the problem is that I am thinking of using the Firebase cloud firestore for this purpose instead of using the news API and I can't figure out how to get the data from the firestore collection. You can look at the following code for reference.

news.page.ts

```js
      import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
      import { NewsService } from '../news.service';
      import { Router } from '@angular/router';

      @Component({
        selector: 'app-news',
        templateUrl: './news.page.html',
        styleUrls: ['./news.page.scss']
      })
      export class NewsPage implements OnInit {
        data: any;
        page = 1;
        constructor(private newsService: NewsService, private router: Router) {}

        ngOnInit() {
          this.newsService
            .getData(`top-headlines?country=us&category=business&pageSize=5&page=${this.page}`)
            .subscribe(data => {
              console.log(data);
              this.data = data;
            });
        }

        onGoToNewsSinglePage(article) {
          this.newsService.currentArticle = article;
          this.router.navigate(['/news-single']);
        }
      }
```

news.service.ts

```js
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
  import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
  const API_URL = environment.apiUrl;
  const API_KEY = environment.apiKey;
  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class NewsService {
    currentArticle: any;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getData(url) {
      return this.http.get(`${API_URL}/${url}&apiKey=${API_KEY}`);
    }
  }
```

news.page.html

```html
  <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>News</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content>
      <ion-card *ngFor="let article of data?.articles" (click)="onGoToNewsSinglePage(article)">
        <!-- <ion-img [src]="article.urlToImage"></ion-img> -->

        <ion-card-content>
          <ion-card-title>{{article.title}}</ion-card-title>

          <p>{{article.description}}</p>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-content>
```

I have installed the angularfire 2 plugin in my project, imported all the files in app.module.ts and also prepared a config file for all the Firebase details. I just want to know how to get the data from Firebase collection and bind it to the html code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling your service `this.newsService.getData(...)` you will have to use firebase service public `AngularFirestore` from `angularfire2/firestore` . Here is an example:

Import the service and inject it in your component `news.page.ts`:

```
import {AngularFirestore} from 'angularfire2/firestore';
...
data: any;
constructor ( public db: AngularFirestore ) {
  }
...
```

To retrieve a single post, create the function

```
getPostEntry ( postTitle: string ): Observable<any> {
    return this.db.collection<any> ( "posts" , ref => ref.where ( 'title' , '==' , postTitle ) ).valueChanges ();
  }
```

This will search all entries in your firestore collection called `"posts"` with attribute `title` being your `postTitle`.

Simillarly to retrieve all posts

```
getAllPosts (): Observable<any> {
    return this.db.collection<any>( "post" ).valueChanges ();
  }
```

Then invoke the functions and consume the observables. For instance you can do it in your ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit() {
            this.getAllPosts().subscribe((data)=>{
                this.data = data;
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
```

Now you have your data in your variable `data`, you just have to draw it in your html as you would normally do. Have in mind that it will probably be an array with all your posts (if there are any).

here is a gist with the code I edited from your class:

https://gist.github.com/HugoJBello/73fb3c5c0964f29934a2d8021efb128d

**EDIT**

renamed firebase collection and added subscription to observable

Comment: Can you also help me on how to use the data in news.page.ts because i am new o angular/ionic and if I am trying to do it by myself, then it is not returning anything. I also tried logging to the console but again it showed nothing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure that you have data in your firestore  database in a acollection named "news" for the example to work. Also if you want to retrieve them by searching by name, add a "name" attribute.

Comment: You need to subscribe to the observables that you created invoking the functions and grab your data asynchronously from them. I'll write you a snippet as soon as I am in front of a keyboard .

Comment: I have a collection named posts in my firestore database and I am using the same in my get function but it still not working.

Comment: @pulkit aggarwal , I edited the answer, take a look and tell me how you see it. Also here is a gist with all of it https://gist.github.com/HugoJBello/73fb3c5c0964f29934a2d8021efb128d